# Redesigning custompanel upon userclick in C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, richtextbox, panel, splitcontainer, custom-panel

I am using C# in a WinForm on Visual Studio 2010. I made a custompanel with 10 richtextboxes inside it. Each richtextbox refers to a column in a table of custompanels. The custompanels load inside of a splitcontainer at runtime.  When the user clicks on the custompanel, it should reduce to half the size but with only 4 specific textboxes. How can I do this? To recap: I need the custompanel to reduce to 4 textboxes from 10 when the user clicks on it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where is the hangup?  Remove the unwanted TextBoxes and store them in a List or something (or just disable them), then change the Size() property of the panel.  Reverse the process to make it grow again.